# I would like to get 1.68 instead of 1.679999999 as I data-import from access db in MFC, C++

Tags: c++, mfc

[image]

Hello :) I would like to import the data I marked as red.

after connecting my program to DB,
I executed this line

`m_strE37 = m_command.GetString(37);`

but unfortunately, m_strE37 stores "1.6799999999999"

their class is as follows

```
CString m_strE37;
typedef CCommand<CDynamicsStringAccessorW,CRowset> DbCommand;
DbCommand m_command;'
```

I Selected that record(row) and tried to get the value by using GetString(37) since it is 37th column.

I was quite new to this DB Process.

Can anyone help me to correctly get 1.68 ??

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the wild, wild world of [floating point math](http://floating-point-gui.de). That result is correct. If you want to round for display, knock yourself out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```
float f = atof(m_strE37);
m_strE37.Format("%3.2f",f);
```

For unicode :

```
float f = atof(CStringA(m_strE370.GetString()));
m_strE37.Format(L"%3.2f",f);
```

Comment: Do you also process data like this ?
Or can you tell me an alternative?
I believe experts will not do like this

Comment: For Unicode you can use `float f = _wtof(m_strE37)`

Comment: @AntonioSEO: Try data exchange of Access dB records with  PODs instead of CString. A value of 1.68 in dB is not supposed to be read as "1.6777" in the first place.

Comment: @seccpur: The value 1.68 cannot be represented as an IEEE-754 floating point number. The closest number that can is 1.67999994754791259765625.